# Activity Indicator question

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiactivityindicatorview

My app main view is a tableview with several rows that can be drilled down.

When a row is clicked, I fetch the sub items using core data which could take a fraction of a second to several long seconds depending on how much items are fetched. (0 to thousands)

Placing activity indicator when fetch takes long time is a great UI while placing it for just one short moment isn't look so good...

What is the common solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at MBProgressHUD http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MBProgressHUD 
This is a sweet Solution for your issue.